# Typescript object type inferring

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible for ts to infer the type by the content of the object?

Such as:

```js
type MyKeyList =
    | "A"
    | "B"
    | "C"
    ;

type MyType<T extends MyKeyList> = {
    type: T,
    value: T extends "A"
        ? 1
        : T extends "B" ? 2 : 3
};


// error for not defining value = 2
const MyObject: MyType = {
    type: "B"
}
```

Does there exist any way to achieve this kind of check?
Or it is just impossible to have.

#### edit

Above is an oversimplified version. This is more close to the actual case I'm trying to deal with. Please don't mind if the following type makes sense, it is just a made-up type.

```js
type Type1 = 
    | "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "H" | "I" | "J" | "K" | "L" | "M" 
    | "N" | "O" | "P" | "Q" | "R" | "S" | "T" | "U" | "V" | "W" | "X" | "Y" | "Z";

type Type2 = 
    | "AA" | "BB" | "CC" | "DD" | "EE" | "FF" | "GG" | "HH" | "II" | "JJ" | "KK" | "LL" | "MM" 
    | "NN" | "OO" | "PP" | "QQ" | "RR" | "SS" | "TT" | "UU" | "VV" | "WW" | "XX" | "YY" | "ZZ";

type Type3 = true | false | "AAA" | "BBB" | "CCC";

type Field1Type<
    T extends Type1, 
    S extends ("AA" | "BB" | "CC" | undefined) = undefined
> = (value: number) => `${T}-${S}-${number}`;

type Field2Type<T extends ("X" | "Y" | "Z")> = 
    (value: boolean) => `${boolean}-${T}`;

type Field3Type<
    T extends Exclude<Type1, "X" | "Y" | "Z">,
    S extends ("AA" | "BB" | "CC")
> = (value: string) => `${T}-${string}-${S}`

type MyType<
    T extends Type1, 
    S extends Type2, 
    U extends Type3
> = {
    t: T,
    s: S,
    u: U,

    field1: U extends true 
        ? Field1Type<T>
        : S extends ("AA" | "BB" | "CC")
            ? Field1Type<T, S>
            : never,

    field2: T extends ("X" | "Y" | "Z")
        ? Field2Type<T>
        : never,

    field3: U extends (true | false)
        ? never
        : T extends ("X" | "Y" | "Z")
            ? never
            : S extends ("AA" | "BB" | "CC")
                ? Field3Type<Exclude<T, "X" | "Y" | "Z">, S>
                : never,
};


const tmp: MyType = {
    t: "A",
    s: "AA",
    u: true,
};
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKqpzN) meet your needs? If so I could maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is an oversimplified version. The real case I'm working on is too complex to just use the map. It contains two generic arguments with each having 20+ keys.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] which more accurately conveys the situation you are facing; otherwise it's hard for others to know how to advise.  One could certainly perform the union distribution in a way that more closely preserves the conditional type in your question, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJqADm), but a conditional type is not recommended for examples like the one you've presented.  Perhaps you can improve the example?

Comment: I've edited the example. Sorry for not giving enough infos. The second method you posted looks promising I'll try if this method can work out, but I'm a bit curious about the way it's not recommended for this kinda case. I'm new to typescript, not quite understand to whole type system.

Comment: Could you fix the example so it's actually a [mre]? Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wggDyw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: My bad, I've changed it so it can pass the compilation except for declaring var.

Comment: @jcalz The second method you provided worked out just fine. I really appreciate that. But I still want to know the reason conditional types are not recommended for this.

Comment: I will write up an answer explaining things when I get a chance.

Comment: Your new example produces a union with ~4000 members, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy4onm); while TS can handle such unions, you would have problems if it grows by an order of magnitude, which can easily happen if you add more type parameters.  Is the new example indicative of the actual size of things, or can it be significantly larger?

Comment: Your new example has a bunch of members with required properties of type `never`; this can't be satisfied by any value, so I'm not sure why you're doing that.  What is its purpose? For example, what use is `MyType<"A", "AA", false>`? Example code should not raise unrelated questions; unless you *want* to talk about properties of type `never`, you might want to [edit] again so that `MyType<T, S, U>` is always something reasonable for any valid choice of `T`, `S`, and `U`.

Comment: BTW, I might as well explain the "not recommended" part here, because I don't know if this question will reach a state that I feel comfortable answering.  The compiler cannot reason about generic conditional types very well; see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for example.  It is at least somewhat better about generic indexed access types, so if you can write a type function to be a property lookup instead of a conditional type, you should do that. So `{a: string, b: number}[K]` is preferable to `K extends "a" ? string : K extends "b" ? number : never`.

Answer (score 0):

As jcalz suggests, using [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDSEQBkCWBnYUC8BYAUFFAD5QBEAgmQUaWQELWEnkDCTRA3AQaJLCAAq4aNgGIUGLBAAewCADsAJuiioFAMwgAnKIKgB+PVFnzlquBLSZDUAN40ofCAC49AGkcA3AIYAbAFdXY1NFFXIqWwBGKDd9UPNyRlsAJlioAGYCAF90hQgvHTyCnR58AHoAKicRAWF+MQdmImc3SjJuZqhfQOCoztzSJqIWkTbGTpHu-yC3FIGWYZHWtg7HIh7ZzIXK8rKCAGMAewUbOAB5ACMAKwgD4Dc4etF7RxWGJmygA) kind of method to unwarp the generic into union can do the trick. Just for types containing more generic arguments, which can be highly nested.